# Laravel - Retrieve specific data from pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I am implemeting a search using Laravel, but couldn't figure out how to get data from my pivot table. The pivot is a many to many relationship between Books and Tags.

The idea here is to search books by tags and display them.

```
class Book extends Model
{
public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Tag extends Model
{
public function books() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

Other search seems to work just fine.

```
$books = Book::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->orWhere('author', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->orWhere('editor', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->orWhere('ISBN', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->orWhere('year', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->orWhere('language', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `withPivot` on the relationship ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns. There is also `wherePivot` than could be useful: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: I've tried. Couldn't figure out how to filter the tags that match with the input, and display books that relate to those tags.

Comment: If i understand what you want, i think you should use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). if you want more detailed information just ask me to explain it in more detail

Comment: whereHas works just fine. Thanks a lot mate!